# gojs makeImageData using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gojs

I'm trying to generate a gojs diagram image using server side nodejs.

Here is my script below, but I can't figure out why `makeImageData` just returns null?  How can I make it return base64 image data.

```
const go = require("gojs");

var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates

const myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, '', // No DOM, so there can be no DIV!
        {
            viewSize: new go.Size(400,400), // Set this property in DOM-less environments
            layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout)
        });

myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Auto",  // the Shape will go around the TextBlock
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { strokeWidth: 0, fill: "white" },
            // Shape.fill is bound to Node.data.color
            new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
            { margin: 8, font: "bold 14px sans-serif", stroke: '#333' }, // Specify a margin to add some room around the text
            // TextBlock.text is bound to Node.data.key
            new go.Binding("text", "key"))
    );


myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    [
        { key: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
        { key: "Beta", color: "orange" },
        { key: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
        { key: "Delta", color: "pink" }
    ],
    [
        { from: "Alpha", to: "Beta" },
        { from: "Alpha", to: "Gamma" },
        { from: "Beta", to: "Beta" },
        { from: "Gamma", to: "Delta" },
        { from: "Delta", to: "Alpha" }
    ]);

myDiagram.addDiagramListener('InitialLayoutCompleted', function() {
    console.log(myDiagram.makeImageData({
        background:'white',
        scale:1,
        type: 'image/png',

    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given here: https://forum.nwoods.com/t/gojs-makeimagedata-using-nodejs/14596/2

> I assume you started from
> https://gojs.net/latest/intro/nodeScript.html.
>
> The problem is that if you want to render images you need to use the
> HTML DOM. But the Node.js environment does not provide an
> implementation of the HTML DOM unless you use Puppeteer or something
> like that.
>
> So this page would be more appropriate:
> https://gojs.net/latest/intro/serverSideImages.html